# Diagnostic monitor for 3 roles (Windows Azure)

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-diagnostics

I'm working on a project with 3 roles (two WebRoles and one WorkerRole) deployed in windows Azure.

My problem is when the instances try to start the Diagnostic monitor (for trace).
Starting the diagnostic monitor from the WorkerRole works fine, but the WebRoles throw  "Unhandled Exception" when they try to start it during the Deployment.

I use the same configuration for all the roles so there is no problem with it.

Thanks,

Comment: Is the exception happening locally (in emulator) or in a deployed service? Also: Can you please edit the question to include the exception?

Comment: The Exception is happening in a deployed service. I can't edit the exception here because there is no number just  [Unhandled Exception] in hosted service. but when i disable the start od diagnostic monitor in the webrole it works !! and no exception is thrown

Answer (score 0):

What storage account are you using? Is it DevStorage by chance? If so, you'll need to provide a real Azure storage account

Comment: Thanks for your post.I'm using a real Azure storage account.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you can post your code and configuration. Please make sure the diagnostics plug-in is configured in csdef and cscfg. You can use the “Enable Diagnostics” CheckBox to simplify the configuration.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.